# Replacing outliers from multiple columns in a dataframe containing NAs using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to replace outliers from a big dataset (more than 3000 columns and 250000 rows) by NA. I want to replace the observations that are greater or smaller than 3 standard deviations from the mean by NA. I got it, doing column by column:

```
height = ifelse(abs(height-mean(height,na.rm=TRUE)) < 3*sd(height,na.rm=TRUE),height,NA)
```

However, I would like to create a function to do that in a subset of columns. To do that, I created a list with the column names that I want to replace the outliers. But it is not working.
Anyone could help me, please?

An example  of my dataset would be:

```
name = factor(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","H"))
height = c(120,NA,150,170,NA,146,132,210,NA)
age = c(10,20,0,30,40,50,60,NA,130)
mark = c(100,0.5,100,50,90,100,NA,50,210)
data = data.frame(name=name,mark=mark,age=age,height=height)
data
```

This was my last try:

```
d1=names(data)
list = c("age","height","mark")
ntraits=length(list)
nrows=dim(data)[1]
for(i in 1:ntraits){
a=list[i]
b=which(d1==a)
d2=data[,b]
for (j in 1:nrows){
                  d2[j] = ifelse(abs(d2[j]-mean(d2,na.rm=TRUE)) < 3*sd(d2,na.rm=TRUE),d2[j],NA)
                  }
}
```

Sorry, I am still learning how to program in R. Thank you very much.
Cheers.

Comment: But the 0.5 in mark is only 1.43 sd's away from the mean. The number of sd's from the mean is not a good way to identify outliers because the sd is so sensitive to outliers -- the value of 0.5 makes the sd huge. Boxplots identify outliers in terms of quartiles and IQR. In any case, the scale function will center and scale all columns of a numeric matrix by any measure of center and spread (default is mean and sd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using apply and scale, scale will omit NAs.  The following code should work:

```
 # get sd for a subset of the columns
 data.scale <-  scale(data[ ,c("age","height","mark") ])

 # set outliers to NA
 data.scale[ abs(data.scale) > 3 ] <- NA

 # write back to the data set
 data[ ,c("age","height","mark") ] <- data.scale
```

Comment: Don't need apply. scale(data[ ,c("age","height","mark") ]) will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used it in a while and forgot it ran on columns automatically.

Comment: Thanks guys. However I have around 3000 columns in total and I want to do it for around 500 of them. Do you know why my loop is not working?

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily long, but it does work. You don't store d2 so it gets replaced on each iteration of the outside loop. Answer by @Jonathan is much more efficient than your program.

Comment: Hey @davep and Jonathan Lisic, the scaling code works perfectly. However, for the purpose of my research I will have to replace the outliers with NA as I described before. Could you please give me a tip in how I can store the d2? I have been trying for so long and didnt get it yet. hahah Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help.